# Make a SWFObject a Link?

Tags: html, css, flash, hyperlink, swfobject

Is it possible to make a link with a .swf flash file, using swfObject?

I would like the entire video to be a clickable link... I'm out of ideas on how to make it happen.

If you go here: http://us.burberry.com/store/menswear/brit/jackets/prod-10000020849-packable-two-in-one-parka/sku-37604181001/
, on the left thumbnails, do you see how they got a swf object to be a link?

Anyone know the principle behind this? How would I do it? It seems like however I lay a div over the flash, my browser will not respond to the click.

I would really like help on this, thank you!

Edit: I cannot make a link directly in the flash file, because 1. I dont have the project file 2. I need to echo PHP code in the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how that page accomplishes that (simplified):

```
.video-thumb-holder,
.video-link {
    position: absolute;
}
.video-link {
    display: block;
    width: 54px;
    height: 96px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xBzWv/1/

Essentially, the z-index is auto and the elements are positioned absolutely, so the flow of the elements (div[object]->a) allows the next element to have a "higher" z-index than the previous element that contains the object.

This example works in FF5. I believe this may be a problem in some browsers/versions (IE6, maybe others), that need alternative methods to put an object in it's correct z-index position.

**EDIT**

In fact, in IE (9) the above does not work.

**EDIT**

IE is using a Flash object, and is using the `<param NAME="wmode" VALUE="transparent">` approach for IE. However, for some reason this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xBzWv/11/ is still not working.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. 

It looks like the Burberry website uses the MP4 format with the `VIDEO` tag. 

Any idea if the `VIDEO` tag will work in IE with the .mov format? I have a .mov in addition to my .swf.... not sure if it will work though.

Comment: Oh gosh. I made a Youtube clone one time, and learned that `.mov` files can be very pernicious, depending. I'd first convert them to something more standard before using it, hopefully stripping all of the useless/stupid crap out first.

Comment: Thank you. I never really played with HTML5 before, will the `VIDEO` tag work with .swf files? Because it makes me wonder that if it really does, why would Burberry use MP4? Sorry to ask so many questions, I actually don't have Internet Explorer available at the moment (I'm on Linux)

Comment: Hmm. I looked at this again and what do you know, IE is NOT using the `VIDEO` (which I should have known, since it's HTML5). However, the console is not updating the markup right after page load. So yes, it is using a Flash object. The trick is supposed to be give the `OBJECT` tag a `PARAM` with `wmode` set to `transparent`, but for some reason in my fiddle I am not able to get it to work. However, the `OBJECT` does accept an `onclick` event (see http://jsfiddle.net/xBzWv/11/), which could be (an easier) workaround. In other words, you might be better of adding the onclick for IE users.

Comment: Hey wait a second, on that Burberry example, are you sure they are using a .swf? I see the .swf path in the object call, but if you navigate to it, all the .swf is is a preloader. The path to the MP4 that is in that object tag seems to contain the actualy video. And this is in Firefox. So they are actually using an MP4?!? Or am I mistaken? (Try taking out the MP4 part of the code in JSFiddle, it won't work) :::EDIT::: Wow, what timing, our posts might overlap a little, considering you submitted 12 seconds before I did

Comment: Although the `onclick` is only a double-click. Sheesh.

Comment: It is an SWF player playing an MP4 video, it just doesn't use the video tag to do it.

Comment: Alright! Okay I got it working in Firefox. Thanks so much for reminding me to use the `wmode` with `transparent`. That was the catch. I appreciate it Jared! Thanks again :)

Comment: Which fiddle are you talking about that doesn't work in IE? The one with the onclick in it? I got hold of a Windows machine and tried the onclick in my `OBJECT` , but it doesn't seem to work. (But then again, it was IE7... hehe) It has that little error icon on the bottom left, it says that `OBJECT` doesn't recognize `onclick`. And yeah, the original `<a>` approach doesn't work either in IE. hm... EDIT: awww I have to learn to read, it looks like you already updated the original post to answer my question. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Your best bet is to absolutely position an `<a>` tag over the video (the `z-index` of the element that contains the swfObject must be lower than that of the `<a>` tag).

Answer (score 0):

To make a solution that works in all browsers I would create a wrapper SWF that loads in the video SWF.  You can then place a button above the video file, and either have it call back to the page using ExternalInterface or pass in the required info from PHP using FlashVars.